# Nil handling at method or constructor level?

Tags: go, struct, null, conventions

Should I check for nil values in the constructor and then set an unexported struct field, or make the default struct value useful by checking for nil at method level?

```
type Foo struct{}

func (f *Foo) Baz() {}

var DefaultFoo = new(Foo)

type Bar struct {
    Foo *Foo
}

func (b *Bar) Baz() {
    if b.Foo == nil {
        DefaultFoo.Baz()
    } else {
        b.Foo.Baz()
    }
}
```

or

```
type Foo struct{}

func (f *Foo) Baz() {}

var DefaultFoo = new(Foo)

type Bar struct {
    foo *Foo
}

func NewBar(foo *Foo) *Bar {
    if foo == nil {
        foo = DefaultFoo
    }
    return &Bar{foo}
}

func (b *Bar) Baz() {
    b.foo.Baz()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a "right" answer for this.

Having said this, the approach usually seen in the Go base libraries is letting the objects be created without any constructor, with `nil` or `zero` values in its fields, and then make the methods have logic to use or return useful defaults.

Take a look at the `http.Client` implementation for example:

https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/net/http/client.go

It will basically let you create a new client by just doing:

```
client := &http.Client{}
```

You can then populate the fields of the object if you want to override defaults, otherwise it'll check for `nil` in different methods to provide default behaviour, for example:

https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/net/http/client.go#L195

```
func (c *Client) transport() RoundTripper {
    if c.Transport != nil {
        return c.Transport
    }
    return DefaultTransport
}
```